# programatically Convert an entity model to a normal object using Reflection (?)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, system.reflection

in codeProject article ( ^[Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127395/Implementing-a-WCF-Service-with-Entity-Framework) ),  By @Mike_Liu,
i was interested in this approach for setting a "Translated Product Entity" class,

```
   private Product TranslateProductEntityToProduct(
            ProductEntity productEntity)
  {
    Product product = new Product();
    product.ProductID = productEntity.ProductID;
    product.ProductName = productEntity.ProductName;
    product.QuantityPerUnit = productEntity.QuantityPerUnit;
    product.UnitPrice = (decimal)productEntity.UnitPrice;
    product.Discontinued = productEntity.Discontinued;
    return product;
  }
```

trying to do it with over 50 Sql Table columns, and for further use on other 
scenarios when needed...

i was wondering how could i have done it not by hard Coding (assigning ) the new product class

i was trying to come up with my approach using system.Reflection but have not succeeded yet

my code so far is :

```
public ObjectResult<tblProd> AsStrigViaEnttFW()
{
    //tco = new tblCustomersObject();
    ObjectResult<tblProd> Res1 = ProdEntt.ExecuteStoreQuery<tblProd>("SELECT * FROM tblProd order by RecordId DESC ");

    //foreach (var item in Res1.())
    //{
    object Prod_Copy = new ProdMasterClass_NewInstnace_ObjGenertator();
    Type t = Prod_Copy.GetType();
    //object pf;
    ////Type Ts = Res1.ElementAt(0).GetType();
    //    pf  = (object)Res1.ElementAt(0);
    var ProdCurObjSet = t.GetProperties();
    if (ProdCurObjSet.Any())

    foreach (var item in ProdCurObjSet)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> Dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();


        var x = (from p
                   in Res1
                 //where p.GetType().Name == item.Name
                 select p).First();
        var y = x.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.Equals(item.Name)).First();
        Dict[item.Name] = from p in Res1 where 
    }
    //var z = pf;//.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p=>p.Name.StartsWith("_")
        var AllProdMembers = Res1.First().GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("_") == false && p.Name.StartsWith("Entity") == false);

        if (AllProdMembers.Any())
        {
            //var propEnttHesMasRes1 = AllProdMembers.GetType().GetProperties();
            var Res1f = Res1.First();
            //object To = new ProdMasterClass_NewInstnace_ObjGenertator();
            //Type t = To.GetType();
            foreach (var Currprop in AllProdMembers)
            {
                var curPrpopEnttName=Currprop.Name;
                var ProdCurObj = t.GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.Equals(curPrpopEnttName));
                if (ProdCurObj.Any())
                {
                    var setterVal = Currprop.GetValue(Res1f, null);
                    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo MatchedPiHesMasObj = ProdCurObj.First();
                    //MatchedPiProdCurObj.SetValue(To, /*Convert.ChangeType(*//*, null), Currprop.PropertyType)*/, null);

                }
            }

        }

    //}

    return Res1;

}
```

... i should not put this here in SO But i was getting so frustrated over some type convertion issuess i've looked in SO For related posts but nothing was actually as i was trying to make in my code (on the fly...).

the "Normal" class was generated (for now)by copying Entity object class

```
public class ProdMasterClass_NewInstnace_ObjGenertator
{



    #region Primitive Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty = true, IsNullable = false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 RecordId
    {
        get
        {
            return _RecordId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_RecordId != value)
            {
                //OnRecordIdChanging(value);
                //ReportPropertyChanging("RecordId");
                _RecordId = value;
                //ReportPropertyChanged("RecordId");
                //OnRecordIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int32 _RecordId;
    //partial voidOnRecordIdChanging(global::System.Int32 value);
    //partial voidOnRecordIdChanged();
      .....
      ///rest of members...
```

and later i was planning to generate it in a more elegant way ..

though for now, i am stuck,the method to copy values from each property of entity to "Translated" object is not done so i guess i might not implementing it properly.

any ideas where to look for this approach in the right direction

Comment: What is the reason that you want to do this? I ask because an `EF` entity is a "normal object" (as you are using the term).

Comment: @KeithPayne i need to pass it as xml to be consumed by other platforms via Restfull Wcf (now testing via android/java )

Comment: [DataMember]
                 public ObjectResult<RobWcf_AssistantServiceHostRest.tblCustomers> InOutAstStringORes
                 {
                     get
                     {
                         return _AstStringORes;
                     }
                     set
                     {
                         _AstStringORes = value;
                     }
                 }

Answer (score 1):

You better don't try to reinvent the wheel (you almost certainly will introduce errors along the way, it will cost you a lot of effort, and reflection is terribly slow). You should use the [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) framework instead - it was made for exactly these kinds of scenarios, it is very mature, feature-rich and there's a lot of practical experience andf documentation on the web.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need minor transformations of the data, as in your sample of `TranslateProductEntityToProduct()` where the only change is casting one value to `decimal`, then I would use the following method to mask and transform the properties are passed along:

```
// Only define properties that are part of the WCF message
public interface IProductXfer
{
    int ProductID { get; }
    string ProductName { get; }
    decimal QuantityPerUnit { get; }
    decimal UnitPrice { get; }
    bool Discontinued { get; }
}

public class ProductEntity : IProductXfer
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    // This is one property that must be transformed ->
    public decimal? QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }
    decimal IProductXfer.QuantityPerUnit { get { return (decimal)(QuantityPerUnit ?? 0m); } }

    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public bool Discontinued { get; set; }

    // These properties are not sent in the WCF message    
    public BitMap Image { get; set; }
    public decimal QuantityOnHand { get; set; }

}
```

Now you can use `IProductXfer` in your WCF message contract while using `ProductEntity` objects everywhere else.

You can use a tool like Resharper to automatically generate the interfaces. Then you only have to go through and code the differences.

- Make sure that you do not tell Resharper (or another similar tool) to replace all usage of ProductEntity with the interface. You only want to use the interface in the WCF message contract.

Comment: thanks for clearing it up, still working on the "What not do" stuff ,the thing is i now better understand the concept. if i suppose to supply (by the settings of the Contract/iterface)type = type(apple) ....i tried to "smuggle" some oranges within the response inside a big apple(: , is that the issue ?

Comment: That is what the WCF contract is for. But the larger problem was that you were doing a lot of work (code) to pass on data that you already had. In fact, one of the goals of `EF` is to reduce the need for that kind of conversion (the convention is to refer to that conversion as *mapping*).